# VisualCode dart analyzer finds many problems in node_modules

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

I have a mixed TypeScript/JavaScript + Flutter monorepo and hence a folder named `node_modules`.

I already excluded it from VSCode via `settings.json`:

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "node_modules": true
  }
}
```

The folder doesn't show up in the explorer pane anymore, but I still get hundreds of false-positive from within `node_modules`.

Is there a way to fully exclude the folder from being analysed by the Dart/Flutte-VSCode-Plugin?

Comment: Maybe check this out https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just putting an `analysis_options.yaml` at the project root (same level as `node_modules`) fixed it:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/** # this precents VSCode from crazily analysing whatever has suffix ".dart" in node_modules
```